# Why is Python open() function not accepting "directory/filename" as an argument?

Tags: python, with-statement

Local environment: Python 3, Bottle, MacOs

Remote environment: Python 3, Bottle, Pythonanywhere

This works in my local environment but not in my remote environment:

```
@route('/test')
def test():
    '''Function tests file open issue.'''
    with open('uploads/Project2.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
        content = ""
        content = file.read()
    return content
```

This works in my remote environment but not in my local environment:

```
@route('/test')
def test():
    '''Function tests file open issue.'''
    with open('uploads', 'r', newline='') as file:
        content = ""
        content = file.read()
    return content
```

In the first case, I pass a *file path* to the open function.  If I pass a *folder name* to it returns this error:

> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'uploads'

In the second case, I pass a *folder name* to the open function.  If I pass a *file path* it returns error:

> NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'uploads/Project2.csv'

I am baffled.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to be certain whether the path exists or not on your remote server.

```
import os 
os.path.exists(<your path>)
```

second, 
you dont have to declare your content variable, you can just declare it 
like this.

```
content = file.read()
```

Third,

```
"uploads" is a directory not a file. Provide a file name in your
directory like you have provided in your local environment. if 
"upload" is not a subdirectory of your code directory, then provide
absolute path. like 
upload = "/home/ubuntu/env/uploads/projects.csv"
```

Comment: Found solution: "uploads" is a subdirectory of code directory but, in remote environment, needed full path to work.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: dont use str, path_exists will be True or False depending upon the existence of path or not. open('uploads', 'r', newline=''), here you are trying to open the whole directory "uploads", please provide filename too, in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

In both environments "uploads" is a subdirectory of the code directory but...

In the local environment a relative path was sufficient:

```
"uploads/file"
```

In the remote environment an absolute path was required:

```
"/home/my_projects/project/uploads/file"
```

I think that this is to do with Bottle being a WSGI object in the remote environment but not in the local environment.